# How to add just once always method?

Tags: java, android

I am pretty new to Android Studio, and i added on my app the possibility to choose between two map apps. But i wanted to know how to add the infamous "Always open with/just once" method.

```
private void launchNextActivity(String latitude, String longitude, int state) {
    for (int i = 0; i < User.getUserCourses().size(); i++) {
        if (User.getUserCourses().get(i).getIdCourse() == course.getIdCourse()) {
            //A remplacer par l'appel de l'api
            Intent intent;

            Location location = getLastKnownLocation();
            if (location == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connexion avec le serveur impossible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            String uri = "google.navigation:q=" + latitude + "+" + longitude;
            uri = uri.replace(" ", "+");
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(uri)).setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            if (intent == null) {
                findViewById(R.id.cancel_button).setClickable(false);
                Snackbar
                        .make(findViewById(R.id.snackbar_position), "Google Map missing", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Download", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                try {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps")));
                                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps")));
                                }
                                findViewById(R.id.cancel_button).setClickable(true);
                            }
                        })
                        .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ShGreen2))
                        .show();
            }

            //Load Waze if available
            Intent wazeIntent;
            String uriWaze = "https://waze.com/ul?ll=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&navigate=yes";
            wazeIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriWaze)).setPackage("com.waze");

            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Ouvrir l'itinéraire avec:");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { wazeIntent });
            reloadActivity(state, chooserIntent);
        }
```

I have searched for almost a week and found almost no info on how this actually works. I know that because i always call a chooser it will always launch it, but how to add the "always open with/just once" without a chooser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [geo URI scheme](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps) to open a location in the user's default map application (which will result in the "always open with/just once" dialog if a default app isn't set).

```
Uri location = Uri.parse("geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what i needed! Works perfectly now. ^^